# get the length of a sound sample in java

Tags: java, audio, sample, duration

i am making an app with Game Maker studio 1.4x it has a function to get sound length but it does work, so i need to make a java or javascript extension to get the sample length (duration) of an included ogg file.

Ive tried a few things but in the java code, it says file exists but when i go to get file length or sound duration it either returns 0 oe undefined.

Ive tried this:

```
public String samplelength(String name) throws IOException  {
    MediaPlayer mp =  new MediaPlayer();
    mp.setDataSource(RunnerActivity.CurrentActivity, Uri.parse(RunnerActivity.CurrentActivity.getFilesDir().toString()+"/"+name));
    mp.prepare();
    double duration = mp.getDuration();
    String lens = ""+duration;
    mp.reset();
    return lens; 
}
```

It always returns undefined

Comment: If it is always returning undefined, then it's likely that the file is either not found, or not being read correctly. First of all I would check that you are storing the .ogg files in the location you specify in the `Uri.parse(...)` call. Otherwise if you have the option, could you try a different file format like mp3 or another supported android audio format and see if the same problem occurs?

Comment: ok il try that, but i always test to see if the file exists in the java, and it says true.

Comment: i tried using a .wav file and a try catch condition.  the error returns setDataSourceFD failed: status=0x80000000

Comment: It seems that this error occurs when the file you are using is corrupt. Did/Can you try a completely different file that has worked before ? (if you have any). Are you recording this sound in the program or is it already pre-recorded and just loaded? If it's recorded, make sure you are releasing the file at the end before trying to open it.

Comment: im using the java code with a game maker studio app.  the ogg file is fine works fine, it is included in the app resources, so on app start i copy the file form the app files to the public accessible folder.  the java test to see if file exists and it does. in manifest i have set internet, read and write to external storage permissions but this is copied to internal folder "data/data/packageid/files/"